Return an array as a comma-list or similar?
I'm trying to construct a normalized table from a JSON file using OPENJSON in SQL Server. The JSON is of the form:
{
  "actions":[
     {"action":"delete","table":"users","key":4}],
     {"action":"update","table":"users","key":5,
      "fields":[{"Name":"FirstName":,"OldValue":"X","NewValue":"Bob"},
                {"Name":"LastName":,"OldValue":"Y","NewValue":"Dobbs"}]
}

My goal is to use these entries in Dynamic SQL to produce a working query:
UPDATE [users] SET [FirstName]='Bob',[LastName]='Dobbs' WHERE [key]=5

Currently I'm using this SQL:
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.actions')
WITH (
  [Action] varchar(25) '$.action',
  [Table] varchar(25) '$.table',
  [Key] varchar(25) '$.key',
  [fields] nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON
 )

Which gives me useful results like:
update   users    5    {"name":...

My original idea was to use string parsing to break out the data in fields, but now I realize that is  bad idea. I believe I can query that back out of the temp table and into the JSON parser and have it break it out into a rowset, but I have looked everywhere and can't find an example that shows this.
Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with the varying-length list of fields?

Can you show us exactly the results you are looking for, its not clear to me from the description.

Are you trying to dynamically build your list of SET columns and the values in your update statement from your json?  That sounds pretty ambitious for tsql.

It shouldn't be too hard to pivot the fields into proper columns and then update your data, hope noone passes drop table users into your table name though, need to be careful here

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

It looks like you need OUTER APPLY and STRING_AGG to break out and re-aggregate the fields property.
Note also

Use sysname for object and column names.
Use QUOTENAME to escape object and column names, use REPLACE for long strings.
I haven't considered INSERT but you should be able to adapt this.

DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
  "actions":[
     {"action":"delete","table":"users","key":4},
     {"action":"update","table":"users","key":5,
      "fields":[{"Name":"FirstName","OldValue":"X","NewValue":"Bob"},
                {"Name":"LastName","OldValue":"Y","NewValue":"Dobbs"}]
  }
]}';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(
  UPPER(j1.action) +
    ' ' +
    QUOTENAME(j1.[table]) +
    CASE WHEN j1.action = 'update'
      THEN '
SET
' + updateFields.allCols
      ELSE ''
    END + '
WHERE [key] = ' +
    CAST(j1.[key] AS nvarchar(10)) +
    ';',
    '
  
')
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.actions')
  WITH (
    action nvarchar(25),
    [table] sysname,
    [key] int,
    fields nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON
  ) j1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
      '  ' + QUOTENAME(j2.Name) + ' = ' + ISNULL('N''' + REPLACE(j2.NewValue, '''', '''''') + '''', 'NULL'),
      ',
'
    )
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.fields)
      WITH (
        Name sysname,
        NewValue nvarchar(max)
      ) j2
) updateFields(allCols)
WHERE j1.action IN ('update', 'delete');

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

db<>fiddle

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend -- yeah, except for the utterly arbitrary 8000 char limit! Thanks for this I'll give it a whirl.

You can always do SELECT @sql instead.

This is working perfectly. I made one minor alteration, I added a comma in the "line string" at the end of STRING_AFF to comma-separate the SET values. The result is exactly what I was looking for.
